# Обработка ответа сервера jQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

На стороне клиента:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setclientname(clientname, clientphone) {
    var url = 'index.php';
    if (confirm("Создать запись?")) {
        $.post( url, {setclientname: clientphone, clientname: clientname }, function (data) {

            alert(data.client_id);

        });
    }
}
</script>
```

На стороне сервера:

```
if (isset($_POST['setclientname'])) {
        @mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients (client_name, client_phone) VALUES ('{$_POST['clientname']}', '{$_POST['setclientname']}')") or die(mysql_error());
        $client_id = mysql_insert_id();
        echo json_encode(array("client_id"=>$client_id));
        exit;
    }
```

При вызове функции setclientname всплывает диалоговое окно, при утвердительном ответе всплывает окошко с текстом "undefined" вместо ожидаемого client_id. При этом запись в таблице успешно создается. Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто в `data` строка, а ее нужно спарсить как объект json'a, для этого используйтe `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @Новичок https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse

Answer (score 0):

Потому что во-первых надо не собачку ставить, а писать проверки:

```
if( !mysql_query( '...' ) ){
    // write log or return FALSE etc.
}
```

посмотреть что где возвращается и на каком этапе теряется значение. сделайте например

```
var_dump( mysql_insert_id() ); // что вернёт?
```

Comment: Я писал в вопросе, что "При этом запись в таблице успешно создается"

Comment: @Новичок хорошо, создалась. `var_dump()` что вернёт?

Comment: Возвращает клиентский id. Более того, если жестко задать значение $client_id = 5, опять-таки всплывает undefined

Comment: @Новичок `console.log(data)` что показывает?

Comment: {"client_id":179}

Comment: Бред какой-то))

Comment: @Новичок так это json, спарси его

Comment: Уже парсил. Результат в комментариях ко второму ответу